# What is wrong with my transpose matrix code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to switch the positions of the rows and columns, or in other words I'm trying to rotate my 4 by 5 matrix by 90 degrees.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define r
#define c 
void rotate(char src[r][c], char dest[c][r]);


int main()
{
    char dest[5][4]; 
char src[4][5]={{'A','B','C','D','E'},
                {'A','B','C','D','E'},
               {'A','B','C','D','E'},
                {'A','B','C','D','E'}};

    cout<<dest[5][4];

}

void rotate(char src[r][c], char dest[c][r]){

int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<r; i++){
        for(j=0; j<c; j++){
            dest[i*c+j]=src[j*c+i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? What happens when you use it?

Comment: `cout<<dest[5][4];` does not work as you expected. It's an attempt to access to an element out of the array bounds.

Comment: `#define c` - define `c` or `r` to be what? Use `const`, avoid using `#define`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes with this code.

## You're not using define correctly.

In the following code section you're simply defining them but not assigning a value to them. So the pre-processor fills in where they're being used with nothing.

```cpp
#define r
#define c
```

If you wanted to use  macros properly for this style of array you would want to do them as follows.

```cpp
#define r <value>
#define c <value>
```

And even then `constexpr` should be used instead in this case. The reason this is prefered is because the variable will have an associated type which will prevent it from being used improperly. And error messages generated from using a define can be much harder to debug than messages from a `constexpr` variable.

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t r = <value>;
constexpr std::size_t c = <value>;
```

## Function Definition

Using templates is a better alternative as they can address several different array inputs. (Basically the compiler will generate different code segments for each different r and c value pairs it can be given), or passing in parameters instead would work as well (this would avoid additional code being generated for each different variant of the function). In the fixed version below I have used templates, because you only have the one *matrix* that you're trying to transpose.

```cpp
void rotate(const char** src, char** dest, std::size_t r, std::size_t c) {
    // ...
}
```

## Array Indexing

Also your way of accessing the array seems to be a bit confused. Since you're treating the array as a 2D array, you need to have 2 indexes on the array. And your row/column order was mixed. Changing it to this solves that problem.

```cpp
template <std::size_t r, std::size_t c>
void rotate(char src[r][c], char dest[c][r]) {
    // Moved the variables within the scope of for loops
    // Changed type from int to size_t.
    // Swapped c and r in the condition for both loops.
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < c; i++){
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < r; j++){
            dest[i][j] = src[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

## Not Using your Function

You also never call your rotate function so that's been added before the finishing output before the program terminates.

## Printing a 2D Array

You also are trying to print the array by accessing a single value so change `cout << dest[5][4]` to the following.

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            cout << dest[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
```

## Corrected Code

With the changes highlighted above the code should yield this output

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

I've given you all the information you need to fix your code.

Comment: `void` is only the return type of the function. So the function doesn't return anything (it doesn't need to), but it does modify the arrays you supply as parameters via pointers.